# Change HTML tag in vim, but keeping the attributes (surround)

Tags: html, vim, surround

Let's say I have a tag (and cursor at *):

```
<h1 class="blah" id="moo">H*ello!</h1>
```

I want to change it to:

```
*<h2 class="blah" id="moo">Hello</h2>
```

i.e. Change the type of tag, but keep all the elements.

Using surround.vim, I could do:

```
cst<h2>
```

but that changes the HTML to:

```
*<h2>Hello</h2>
```

Is just changing the tag possible, but keeping all the attributes? Surround documentation doesn't seem to contain anything like this...

Comment: I'd say keep it KISS and use `s///` if you just want to change tag1 => tag2.

Comment: Good point! It's just a bit of extra work if the tag content spans multiple lines,  I was hoping there'd be an answer with less movement / line number fiddling. Thanks :)

Comment: @timss no, you have to do that twice (once for the opening and once for the closing tag) which is needlessly manual.

Comment: @рытфолд Not at all, just use `s/h1/h2/g` or `set gdefault`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have xml.vim plugin (https://github.com/othree/xml.vim) . If you had it too, your requirement is rather easy.

Just move cursor to tag, press `<leader>c` (lowercase c), then input new tagname,  only tag name will be changed.

If you press `<leader>C` (Big C), also rename the tag/element, but also original attributes are removed.

Comment: Accepting this because I didn't know about the plugin before, and it's full of HTML / XML goodness (and answers the original question). Thanks!

Comment: Note this is now `<LocalLeader>c` which is by default `\c`

Answer (score 135):

Replacing tag while keeping attributes [has been added](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/pull/131) to Surround.vim

`cst<p>` replaces whole tag, while `cst<p` (without closing bracket) keeps attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works as expected without having the closing tag.

Answer (score 46):

You can use `cstt` and it'll display `<` on the bottom and type the tag name without `>`

in this case, `cstth2` and hit enter.

Comment: This is great! I'd also like to know why this works. `cst` from vim-surround makes sense, but what does the extra `t` do?

Comment: I think extra t comes from tag. Like change tag with tag

Comment: Cant create a hotkey for it without using feedkeys, i.e.: `vim.keymap.set({"n", "x"}, "<leader>w", function() vim.fn.feedkeys("cstt") end, {noremap = true})`

Answer (score 2):

Surround does not have this built in. You can yank the attributes and then use `<c-r>"` when typing out the replacement tag to bring them back, but that is a bit lame.

I propose a new mapping and function that will automate this task. The following will provide the `cse` mapping, aka change surrounding element. Put this in a your `~/.vimrc` file or maybe `~/.vim/after/plugin/surround_change_element.vim` if you feel overly orangized.

```
function! s:ChangeElement()
  execute "normal! vat\<esc>"
  call setpos('.', getpos("'<"))
  let restore = @"
  normal! yi>
  let attributes = substitute(@", '^[^ ]*', '', '')
  let @" = restore
  let dounmapb = 0
  if !maparg(">","c")
    let dounmapb = 1
    " Hide from AsNeeded
    exe "cn"."oremap > <CR>"
  endif
  let tag = input('<', '')
  if dounmapb
    silent! cunmap >
  endif
  let tag = substitute(tag, '>*$', '', '')
  exe "normal cst<" . tag . attributes . ">"
endfunction
nnoremap cse :call <SID>ChangeElement()<cr>
```

Note: this will shadow some cases of surroundings with `e` if you have any created via `g:surround_101` or `b:surround_101`. If that is the case change the mapping form `cse` to something else maybe `csn` for change surrounding node.

*EDIT*

[As of February 22, 2015](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/pull/131) this answer is out of date. Please see @Wojtek Kruszewski post or `:h surround-replacements` for how to do this natively with surround.

Comment: ... and this is why I need to learn vim script! I'll have a look at this when I get a chance and see what's going on. Thanks :)

Comment: @nabn thank you for the follow up. I have edited the post

Comment: @cazgp Tim Pope mastered VimScript so that we don't have to #sacrifice

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I would try `matchit.vim` or `text-object`.

### matchit.vim solution:

`matchit.vim` is included in vim.

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/macros/matchit.vim
```

and then `0l%%lr2<Ctrl-o>llr20`.

### text-object solution:

You can also evacuate html content to the register before replace them.

`dit:.s/h1/h2/g<Ctrl-o>P0`